# why is $P[g(X)\leq y]=P[X \leq h(y)]$ for monotonically increasing functions

Tags: probability-distributions, inverse-function

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTT9U.png)

Above is a theorem for how one can find the pdf to the inverse function. I have a problem with the part $P[g(X)\leq y]=P[X \leq h(y)]\: \: \: (a)$

Can someone prove this mathematically? I have tried a little myself I ended up with:

$$P[g(X)\leq Y]=\int_{0}^{g^{-1}(x)}g(x)dx \: \: \: (aa)$$
$$P[h(y)\leq X]=\int_{0}^{h^{-1}(y)}h(y)dy \: \: \: (aaa)$$

Now I am not sure how (aa) and (aaa) are equal. I have also seen some reasoning with the graph of the function one are looking at like the one I have added in the attachment but I dont get this reasoning either. Can someone prove the relation (a) mathematically?

Please tap image to read it.

As a comment to the answer I have addded this:

If $g$ and $h$ are inverses of each other and ar monotonically increasing then:$$g(X)\leq y\implies X=h(g(X))\leq h(y)$$and:

Do you just simply use the invere function on both sides of the equation? How can one prove that using h on both sides of the equation holds?

$$X\leq h(y)\implies g(X)\leq g(h(y))=y$$

So we have $$g(X)\leq y\iff X\leq h(y)$$or equivalently:

How can one just use the equality sign below? I am sure this is related to my first problem. Why would the fraction of outcomes be the same after you have used the inverse?

$$\{g(X)\leq y\}=\{X\leq h(y)\}$$and consequently:$$\mathsf P(g(X)\leq y)=\mathsf P(X\leq h(y))$$

Comment: Note that you should not use $x$ as both an integrand and as a substituent. Same as $y$.

Comment: Let $\omega\in\{g(X)\leq y\}$. Then $g(X(\omega))\leq y$ implying that $X(\omega)\leq h(y)$ or equivalently $\omega\in\{X\leq h(y)\}$. This works for every $\omega\in\Omega$ so $\{g(X)\leq y\}\subseteq\{X\leq h(y)\}$. Likewise we find:$\{g(X)\leq y\}\supseteq\{X\leq h(y)\}$ and conclude that the sets are equal.

Comment: Your own efforts to prove this makes no sense at all. On RHS there are two integrals wrt Lebesgue measure (I guess). But the Lebesgue measure is not involved in this. Also integration is not relevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ and $h$ are inverses of each other and ar monotonically increasing then:$$g(X)\leq y\implies X=h(g(X))\leq h(y)$$and: $$X\leq h(y)\implies g(X)\leq g(h(y))=y$$

So we have $$g(X)\leq y\iff X\leq h(y)$$or equivalently:$$\{g(X)\leq y\}=\{X\leq h(y)\}$$and consequently:$$\mathsf P(g(X)\leq y)=\mathsf P(X\leq h(y))$$

Comment: I have added some question to your answer. Hopefully you can look at them.

Comment: If $h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is monotonically increasing then $a\leq b\implies h(a)\leq h(b)$. Do you agree with that? If so then also $g(a)\leq b\implies h(g(a))\leq h(b)$ right? If $h$ and $g$ are inverses then $h(g(a))=a$ so we found $g(a)\leq b\implies a\leq h(b)$. Likewise we can deduce that $a\leq h(b)$ implies $g(a)\leq b$. Our conclusion is that $g(a)\leq b$ and $a\leq h(b)$ are equivalent statements. Do you understand?

Comment: We apply all this on $X$  which is a function to $\mathbb R$ (not an element). Another route is taking an arbitrary $\omega\in\Omega$ and to prove that $g(X(\omega))\leq y\iff X(\omega)\leq h(y)$. This shows that it is true for **every** $\omega\in\Omega$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get that since $a\leq b$ then $h(a)\leq h(b)$ for monotonically increasing f. But what I dont get is why the probability is conserved that is why is $P(a\leq b)=P(h(a)\leq h(b))$?

Comment: Especially since $b\neq h(b)$. How can then $P(a \leq b))=P(h(a) \leq h(b))$?

Comment: If $h,g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ are monotonic and are inverses of eachother then $g(a)\leq b\iff a\leq h(b)$. Do you agree with that? That means that the statements $g(X(\omega)\leq y$ and $X(\omega)\leq h(y)$ are equivalent, so that the sets $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid g(X(\omega))\leq y\}$ and $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\leq h(y)\}$ **coincide** or if you like **are exactly the same**.

Comment: I am not sure about the part that starts with the line that has $\iff$ in your answer. I dont see what constraints that leads to the same probability for $P(a \leq h(b))$ and $g(a) \leq b$. All though I isolated get every line up until $\iff$ I might not get a message that the lines up until $\iff$ communicate as a sum.

Comment: You can read that line as: for every $\omega\in\Omega$ the statements $g(X(\omega))\leq y$ and $X(\omega)\leq h(y)$ are exactly the same. Consequently the sets mentioned in my former comment are the same, and consequently these sets have the same probability. Formally $P(\{\omega\in\Omega\mid g(X(\omega))\leq y\})=P(\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\leq h(y)\}$, and abbreviated $P(g(X)\leq y)=P(X\leq h(y)$.